# How to discard only mode changes with Git

Tags: linux, permissions, git

I accidentally ran `chmod -R 755 projects` on the directory where I put all my projects.

Fortunately, all my projects are all tracked using git. So I could have run `git checkout HEAD .` inside each projects to fix the permission.

However, in some projects there are some works in progress which are not commited to the tree yet, doing so will override the content for these files.

Is there a way to discard changes only for the file modes, no the file contents?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found this snippet that does exactly what I want.

```
git diff -p \
    | grep -E '^(diff|old mode|new mode)' \
    | sed -e 's/^old/NEW/;s/^new/old/;s/^NEW/new/' \
    | git apply
```

I assigned this snippet to a git alias then I can type `git fix-perm` in directories where permissions are messed up.

```
git config --global alias.fix-perm "!f(){ git diff -p | grep -E '^(diff|old mode|new mode)' | sed -e 's/^old/NEW/;s/^new/old/;s/^NEW/new/' | git apply; }; f"
```

Credits go to jtdp. (https://gist.github.com/jtdp/5443498)

Comment: There is something weird with the last command. `!f` is replaced by bash with the last history command that starts with an `f`

Comment: yeah it would be sensible to single-quote the outer expression

Comment: added `--cached` because I had already staged the changes - still got an error, despite everything looking fine: `error: git diff header lacks filename information when removing 1 leading pathname component (line 2)`

Comment: So here is my not yet working version, including a sed simplification:
`git diff --cached --patch | grep -E '^(diff|old mode|new mode)' | sed -e 's/^old/new/;t;s/^new/old/' | git apply`

Comment: Had to disable copy detection: `git -c diff.renames=no diff --cached --patch | grep -E '^(diff|old mode|new mode)' | sed -e 's/^old/new/;t;s/^new/old/' | git apply`

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, it is likely because your files are on an ExFAT drive, which doesn't support permissions at all. These are the wages of those who trifle with Microsoft technology. :(

If that's not your case, you may have an ACL on the volume due to Apple File Sharing, which also can't be overcome via any kind of file reset.  These are the wages of those who trifle with Apple technology. :D

Answer (score 5):

Run this command.

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

For more info, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes). It has helped me.

Comment: This does not discard the file mode changes, it only ignores them!

Comment: Absolutely, but in some cases, that's what can be required (such as when windows refuses to remove the permission changes even with the command from the main answer)